# Problem in triggering an update in one sql table when the other is changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to create a trigger that updates a Product table's P_total_Sale column when there is a an update in sales table. For example when we make a sale of 500 for P_ID 1 in sales table. Then it should change P_total_Sale to 3100. Below is the image of table. First table is 'tb_sales', second is 'tb_product'.

[image]

Now problem is that i the code i wrote makes update for all the products. Let me show you the result.
This is the code

```
create trigger update_product_sales
on tb_sales  
after insert
as   
begin
update tb_product   
set P_total_sale = P_total_sale + tb_sales.S_price
from tb_sales
where tb_product.P_ID = tb_sales.P_id
raiserror('Product table updated',16,2)
end
```

And this is the insert query

```
insert into tb_sales
values(6,'2008-08-30',400,'Jensen',1)
```

This the output i get

[image]

I want to know what am i doing wrong and how to resolve it. Thank You.

Comment: That seems a bit dangerous. Every time someone updates the price, the new price will be ADDED to the old amount. You should be adding the change in the price between the old and new values. Your totals will become incorrect very quickly.

Comment: My bad .. while your question says that you update the sales table, I see that your trigger is for insert and delete only.

How do you expect the results of a delete to work?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I haven't yet thought about the deletion. I am actually new in triggers. Once i am done with this insertion problem then i'll adjust it for more range of operations.

Comment: I would just remove the delete option from the trigger. You can create a second trigger later that handles delete. It's often better to split out your logic to make things less confusing.

Comment: Yes, that's actually a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try with below code snippet.
You have to update total sale only for new added "P_ID". (not for all P_ID)

```
create trigger update_product_sales
on tb_sales  
after insert,delete 
as   
begin
update tb_product   
set P_total_sale = P_total_sale + INSERTED.S_price
from INSERTED
where tb_product.P_ID = INSERTED.P_id

end
```

Comment: I understand that i only have to do for the newly inserted entry. I tried inserted.P_id but it's giving me "multi-part identifier could not be bound" error

Comment: Sorry my bad. I forgot to update from table statement.  Please try with updated code.

Comment: Now the error is on P_total_sale and P_ID column. It's saying invalid column name